# Remove Item from array in Local storage using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, local-storage

**Overview:** Front-end based wish list

**Technology:** HTML5 (localStorage), CSS and jQuery

**Functionalities:** Add item, delete item before reload, real time count

**Problem:** If I add product, reload and try to remove it from the array it will not work.

**Code where I am not sure how to solve the problem:**

```js
$("#wish_list_item").on("click", ".w-premove", function() {
$product_id = $(this).attr("wpid");
$("#list_id_" + $product_id).remove();
wish_list = $.grep(wish_list, function(n, i) {
  return n != $product_id;
});
localStorage.setItem(wishlistkey, JSON.stringify(wish_list));
show_message("Product removed");
count_items_in_wishlist_update();
});
});
```

**Link to my fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/3ybwf3c3/4/

**Solution:** https://jsfiddle.net/3ybwf3c3/6/

**Code:**

`$("tr.wishlist-item").each(function(index, el) { 
    wish_list.push(el.outerHTML);
});`

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself. The current code is simultaneously too much code and too little; we'll want to see the HTML the code works on, but I doubt that we need all of that JavaScript. Please try and reduce the code to the minimum necessary to recreate the error.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have reduced the JS and still provided link to the fiddle. Hope this helps.

Comment: Click on the "Run code snippet" button. Do you see a result? No? Then it's not complete, or verifiable. Think of it this way; you're asking someone to debug your code. Would you give that person all of the code needed to help you with your problem? Or would you give that person a little bit of code that doesn't even run?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan apologies, not sure why my JSFIddle link did not appear. Since the code editor here runs in sandbox I have updated the ticket with the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
wish_list = $.grep(wish_list, function (n, i) {
    return n != $product_id;
});
```

`n` contains the HTML string for an entire `tr` element, but `$product_id` is just a string ID. So everything matches, and you put all rows back into local storage.

Since you removed the product from the DOM, you could just re-query the DOM for the new HTML strings:

```
wish_list = [];

$("tr.wishlist-item").each(function(index, el) { 
    wish_list.push(el.outerHTML);
});
```